# About owner drawn (custom widget)

Tags: android

I'm considering to develop owner drawn EditText widget.
So, what do you think I should read or refer, firstly?
Or, could you give me some good examples of both owner drawn widget or custom widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement your own widgets you have to extend View or subclass of View. I think that a good start is Romain Guy presentation from Google IO:
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's informative link, however not quite much relative with question.